# Python Flask template update

Tags: python, flask

I have a very basic question (first time i use Flask, i am not used to web frameworks).

I would simply like to update variables in a template e.g. hello.html nothing else (i don't care about routes or anything at the moment)

i do that according to a tutorial:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


x=1986

res=render_template('hello.html', myVar = x)

print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Please note that i have a html file name hello.html in a subdir called templates.
hello.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>Hello {% print(myVar) %}</h1>

   </body>
</html>
```

what am i doing wrong?

edit. i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask_test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    res=render_template('hello.html', myVar = x)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

P.s. sorry about my "clumsyness" with web frameworks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible that your code structure would work. The basic concept in `flask` is context. Normally you can think that is a complete scope for a single request.

So as you can see in your error message, `ctx` which is context is `None`. You cannot use `render_template` like this.

Instead, you can directly use the underlying render engine used by `flask`: `jinja2`.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, select_autoescape
env = Environment(
    loader=FileSystemLoader('your/templates/dir'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
)
template = env.get_template('hello.html')
x = 1986
print(template.render(myVar = x))
```

And your template should be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>Hello {{ myVar }}</h1>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic Thanks !  this is exactly what i was looking for! you really save me some time.

Comment: Wow amazing answer .For this T had spend 2 days .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what tutorial you're following but I'm pretty sure it didn't show that structure.

You need to put your code within a function and decorate it with the URL you want to use; and then you need to return the rendered template from the function, rather than printing it.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    x = 1986
    res = render_template('hello.html', myVar=x)
    return res
```

Also, you don't use `print()` within a template; to output the value of a variable you use `{{ }}` instead of `{% %}`.

```
<h1>Hello {{ myVar }}</h1>
```

Comment: thanks, yes indeed there was this kind of structure (that you gave in the tutorial). It runs without error, however what i want is simply to get the actual text content , i.e. res from within my code , like resOutside=index() and then print(resOutside) but this fails